# Uncaught handler for message of type “…” already added

Tags: javascript, r, callback, shiny

I am working with `Shiny` and `JavaScript`. I extend the functionality of `Shiny` with `JavaScript`. Doing that, I work with [callbackHandlers](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/server-to-client-custom-messages.html). 
I observe the userinput with a `click event` implemented in `JS`. Once the event is fired, I send the needed data to `R`, where a function works with the data. The results again get send back to `JS` where the display of the data handled.

So. on my `JS` side I have something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
    radioButtons[i].onclick = function() {
        if (parseInt(this.value) === 10) {
            Shiny.onInputChange("go", this.value);
            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("someCallbackHandler1", function(someJson) {
                someFunction(someJson);
            });

        } else if (parseInt(this.value) === 11) {
            Shiny.onInputChange("go", this.value);
            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("someCallbackHandler2", function(someJson) {
                someFunction(someJson);
            });
       }  // more else if checking for the value
       ....
```

On the `R` side I do this

```
observe({
if( !is.null(input$go) ) {
    if( (input$go == 10) ) {
        sendToJs1[["myJson"]] <- someFunctionIwrote(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
        session$sendCustomMessage(type = "someCallbackHandler1", sendToJs1$myJson)

    } else if( (input$go == 11) ) {
        sendToJs2[["myJson"]] <- someFunctionIwrote(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6)
        session$sendCustomMessage(type = "someCallbackHandler2", sendToJs2$myJson)

   } # more else if checking for which value gets send from js
   ....
```

When I click on the `radioButton` with the value `10`, then on the `radioButton` with the value `11` and **then** again on the `radioButton` with the value `10` I get this.

> Uncaught handler for message of type “ someCallbackHandler1” already added

So `JS` notices that the `callbackHandler1` is already added and does not add it again. But I need it to be added again in order to display the data. Further, what would `JS` do if the input data changes and `someFunctionIwrote(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)` is executed with different input data? Of course the `callbackHandler1` is already added, but whats *inside*, the results send from `R` to `JS` is different.

How would I manage this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be:

1. Define your javascript event handlers only once, and outside your loops. No need to define them more than once. They will continuously listen to the messages from the server once they have been created.
2. Make sure that the callback functions stated in the handlers are flexible enough to handle all your server responses. So your function `someFunction()` should be able to handle all possible messages from the server.

So the code would be:

```
// function to be called from inside the callback functions:
function someFunction(someJson){
 console.log("No matter what someJson is, I will handle them all properly!");
...
}

// set the event handlers for message from server:
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("someCallbackHandler1", function(someJson) {
                someFunction(someJson);
            });
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("someCallbackHandler2", function(someJson) {
                someFunction(someJson);
            });

// set the event handlers for radio button clicks:
for(var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
    radioButtons[i].onclick = function() {
        if (parseInt(this.value) === 10) {
            Shiny.onInputChange("go", this.value);
        } else if (parseInt(this.value) === 11) {
            Shiny.onInputChange("go", this.value);
       }  // more else if checking for the value
```

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot! That works. Putting the `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` outside the loop worked! I wonder why, could you clarify?

Comment: When you create an event listener that has already been created, Shiny will not accept that. I do not know the exact reason for this; but this is the way they made it work.